# Stuck with adding variable to Discord Client object Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

Im new to Typescript and writing a Discord bot using Typescript. I want to add a variable "commands" to the Client object. For example in Javascript, you using this:

**Javascript**

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
client.commands = 'commands';
console.log(client.commands);
// 'commands'
```

but now I want to add something similar to Typescript. But when Im using this in Typescript, I got the following error:

```
Property 'commands' does not exist on type 'Client'.ts(2339)
```

How can I solve this?

My code at the moment:

```js
export class HalloClient {

    private client: Client; 

    constructor() {
        this.client = new Client();

        this.client.commands = new Collection();
    }

    public start(): void {
        console.log(`- Client | Starting process...`);

        new RegisterEvents('../events/', this.client).load();
        new MongoConnection(process.env.mongouri).createConnection(); 

        console.log(this.client);

        this.client.login(process.env.token);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you typing in TypeScript ?

Comment: I have this in my TS file
```javascript
export class HalloClient {

    private client: Client; 

    constructor() {
        this.client = new Client();

        this.client.commands = new Collection();
    }

    public start(): void {
        console.log(`- Client | Starting process...`);

        new RegisterEvents('../events/', this.client).load();
        new MongoConnection(process.env.mongouri).createConnection(); 

        console.log(this.client);

        this.client.login(process.env.token);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same issue when using typescript and following the guide from [https://discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/)

By default, `commands` is not an existing attribute type on `Discord.Client` object, but you can easily extend Discord.js typings with your own type by creating a `.d.ts` file.

I have `discord.d.ts` file on my project directory, and it contains:

```
declare module "discord.js" {
    export interface Client {
        commands: Collection<unknown, any>
    }
}
```

This fixes my issue.

Or even better if you are using the single-file style command from [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/):

```
import { Message } from "discord.js";

declare module "discord.js" {
    export interface Client {
        commands: Collection<unknown, Command>
    }

    export interface Command {
        name: string,
        description: string,
        execute: (message: Message, args: string[]) => SomeType // Can be `Promise<SomeType>` if using async
    }
}
```

This way, you also get code completion when accessing a command object from `this.client.commands.get("commandName")`, and you also can import `Command` type if you need it from `import { Command } from "discord.js"`.

I find this useful when I want to strictly type my exported command from my command file, for example:

```
import { Command } from "discord.js";

// Now `command` is strictly typed to `Command` interface
const command: Command = {
    name: "someCommand",
    description: "Some Command",
    execute(message, args): SomeType /* Can be Promise<SomeType> if using async */ {
        // do something
    }
};

export = command;
```

Comment: in the example above where you say: 
`execute: (message: Message, args: string[]) ...`

I would like to understand the reason of the string[]. Because in the discord.js example they use: 
`async execute(interaction) {
  await interaction.reply('Pong!');
}`
having args as parameter i couldnt call the reply function. Could you explain this please a bit further :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by creating a `discord.d.ts` file in my project root with the content below:

```
import type { Client } from 'discord.js'

declare module 'discord.js' {
  export interface Client extends Client {
    commands: Collection<unknown, any>
  }
}
```

This simply extends the `Client` type from the library and re-exports it.