# Discord.js Guide : Property 'commands' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>' in Typescript

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

`node:v16.11.0`
`"discord.js": "^13.2.0"`

I am setting up an example Discord.js bot.

In [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files), I am to the point of adding this line:

`client.commands = new Collection();`

Typescript then complains with: `Property 'commands' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860164/stuck-with-adding-variable-to-discord-client-object-typescript) seems to be in the same vein as what I want. However I'm still running into some problems. If I add a `declare module "discord.js"` and declare new typings, it doesn't seem to extend the existing type, it overwrites it. And when when I do, it doesn't know what a `Collection` is in my custom typings file, since that's custom to the new Discord.js library. I can't help but feel this shouldn't be required in an official guide.

I'm wondering if anyone else has made a typescript Discord bot and found a newer solution to this problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've yet to try this but: Try creating a new class that `extends` discord.js's `Client` and add whatever entries you need. Typings should be carried onto the new class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

-Edit-

So I had the opportunity of finding my own question in a search and seeing I'd originally answered the question wrong. It turns out that the reason we are getting this error when following the Discord.js guide is because there is no `commands` property on the Client class at all. It's just a pattern that the guide uses and Typescript calls it out.

Once I had Typescript set up correctly for my project, adding that commands was going to represent a `Collection<any, any>` worked fine.

`src/@types/discord.d.ts`

```
import { Collection } from "discord.js";

declare module "discord.js" {
  export interface Client {
    commands: Collection<any, any>;
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"],
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json"
}
```

---

-Old Answer-

Okay. So I figured it out.

Create `types/common/discord.d.ts`

And don't do what I did and just include this:

```
declare module "discord.js" {
  export interface Client {
    commands: Collection<unknown, any>
  }
}
```

Make sure this is at the top.

```
import { Collection } from "discord.js";
```

Then it will actually extend the existing one and bring in `Collection` for the definition instead of replacing it.

This solution also required `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"` to be added to es-lint, thanks to `Collection` extending `Map` and taking any value.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The `import { Collection }` line now throws the following errors `Circular definition of import alias 'Collection'.ts(2303)` and `Module '"discord.js"' declares 'Collection' locally, but it is not exported.ts(2459)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options go: the hard way or the easy way. The hard way is this:

```
declare module "discord.js" {
  export interface Client {
    commands: Collection<unknown, any>
  }
}
```

And the easy way is to extend the discord class which is what everyone does:

```
// utils/Client.ts
import { Client, Collection } from "discord.js"

export default class MyClient extends Client {
  collection: Collection<any, any> // use correct type :)
  constructor(options) {
   super(options)
   this.collection = new Collection();
   this.loadCommands()
  }
  loadCommands() {
   // enter code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still shows the error: Property 'commands' does not exist on type 'Client<true>', but in IDE that error doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already answered but for those who don't want to import stuff just do this:

```
module "discord.js" {
    export interface Client {
        foo: number;
    }
}

export {}
```

Comment: Do this where? please share more info about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files). it is recommended to extend the base Client and typecast it to add the commands property. You can achieve this by creating a new interface as follows:

```js
interface ClientWithCommands extends Client {
  commands: Collection<string, any>
}
```

Once you have defined the interface, you can proceed with typecasting the Client instance using the "as" keyword:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  ],
}) as ClientWithCommands
```

Now, you can proceed to add the commands as follows:

```js
client.commands = new Collection()
...
```